# Collapse nested objects into flat map with dotted properties

Tags: javascript, tree

I have an object like this

```
{
  "CPU": {
    "Architecture": {
      "X86": 0,
      "Other": 0,
      "X86_64": 6
    }
  },
  "Platform": {
    "Os": {
      "Mac": 0,
      "Linux": 5,
      "Other": 0,
      "Windows": 0
    }
  }
}
```

How to to convert it to map like this?

```
"CPU.Architecture.X86": 0
"Platfrom.Os.Mac":0
"Platfrom.Os.Linux":5
```

Can there already be ready-made solutions?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/kirbysayshi/2ea881ebe643458311f4#gistcomment-1913598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, assuming your object are simply created from data:

```
function flatten(obj, prev = "", res = {}){
   for(f in obj){
     if (obj.hasOwnProperty(f)){
       if(obj[f].constructor === Object){
          prev = prev + f + ".";
          flatten(obj[f], prev, res);
       }else{
         res[prev + f] = obj[f];
       }
     }
   }    
   return res;
}

let a = {
  "CPU": {
    "Architecture": {
      "X86": 0,
      "Other": 0,
      "X86_64": 6
    }
  },
  "Platform": {
    "Os": {
      "Mac": 0,
      "Linux": 5,
      "Other": 0,
      "Windows": 0
    }
  }
};


console.log(flatten(a))
```

It will use the [for... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```
// more consisely
function flatten(obj, prev = "", res = {}){
   for(f in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(f)){
     if (obj[f].constructor === Object){
        if(typeof obj[f] !== "object") res[prev + f] = obj[f];
        else flatten(obj[f], prev + f + ".", res);
     }
    }
   }    
   return res;
}
```

Comment: The non-JSON solution is currently missing a check for `null`. An alternative to `for ... in` + `hasOwnProperty()` is `Object.keys`.

Comment: I'd say e.g. `{a:{b:null}}` should become `{a.b:null}` - so no special treatment from other primitives.

Comment: Will `typeof obj[f] === "object"` also be true when the value is an array—creating a false positive? Maybe refactor to `obj[f].constructor === Object`.

Comment: @IliasT `typeof array === "object"` evaluates to true, but it's not a false positive as arrays are objects. If you want to exclude them: since objects can have array indices (not only arrays), would you also want to exclude objects whose keys are all array indices?

Comment: it will do `CPU.Architecture.X86.0`  &  `CPU.Architecture.X86.1` which imo is wrong.

Comment: @le_m ok, but how about `typeof null === 'object'`, what does that evaluate to?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to concatenate nested object property keys, there is no built-in function for that. However, it is quite simple to implement your own solution:

```js
// Concatenate nested object property keys with a dot:
function dotnotation(obj, dst = {}, prefix = '') {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    if (val && typeof val == 'object') dotnotation(val, dst, prefix + key + '.');
    else dst[prefix + key] = val;
  });
  return dst;
}

// Example:
console.log(dotnotation({a:{b:1, c:2}, d:3})); // {'a.b':1, 'a.c':2, 'd':3}
```

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is part of the upcoming ES2017 standard.